# Why does IMPORTRANGE not import data from a formula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets to copy data from a "data prep" sheet to a sheet my sales team uses. Somehow in one of the IMPORTRANGES it does import everything but the data that I added with a formula.

Formula is:

```
`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VWprxZwaMoHmA1X7xyW-ZQW-mVL01uM8s72qlnTAWvc/edit","Input Buyers!A:E")`
```

Googles Example Formula is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hh2grfB6rp9OQ2yAIu3S5YF_CCFJGwyqPGveABlOZKg/edit", "World Cup!A1:D21")
```

Is this a known issue? Seems super esoteric as I have other IMPORTRANGES where this works.

Screenshot for detailed explanation:

Left is the data prep sheet, right is importing. You can see the `IMPORTRANGE` on right `A1` including the correct ULR and range.
On the left `D2` has a formula (where I match the owner with the buyer) in the top version and just text in the bottom version.
In the top it does not import the owner, in the bottom it does.

[image]

Comment: Put your formula to post.

Comment: @Harun24HR
=IMPORTRANGE("LINK to Sheet","Input Buyers!A:E")

Answer (score 1):

It seems that quotes around the sheet name are missing.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("LINK to Sheet","'Input Buyers'!A:E")
```

instead of

```
=IMPORTRANGE("LINK to Sheet","Input Buyers!A:E")
```

Comment: Hi Goran, thanks for your comment!
Unfortunately this does not solve it and it is also not a requirement from Google to use this.
See here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en-GB

Google Tool Tip Example (when you enter =importrange and hit enter it opens a contect menu) is this:
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hh2grfB6rp9OQ2yAIu3S5YF_CCFJGwyqPGveABlOZKg/edit", "World Cup!A1:D21")

Comment: The only additional thing that comes to mind is - did you approve access to the source spreadsheet you are importing from?

Comment: Yes I did.
In the screenshot you can see that some also imports. Just the column with a formula doesn't. It does import, when it is not a formula (when I add the formula back to it, it removes the values again).

It is super weird. But I read in another forum that importrange is not always reliable.

Comment: what kind of formula, Is it a custom formula returning an array, or ARRAYFORMULA?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data format in the source sheet. I had the same issue and changing from 'Automatic' to 'Text' worked just fine.